# What is the difference between string1 == string2 and your own for-loop comparison?

Tags: c++, string-comparison

Say you want to compare two strings in C++ to see if they are the same. Aside from less typing, is there any difference between the following? Is one faster than the other, and is there a better way to compare the strings than what is contained here?

Version A:
`if( string1 == string2 ) { return true; }`

Version B:

```
// Check for equal length, then...
for( int i = 0; i < string1.length(); ++i ) {
    if( string1[i] != string2[i] ) { return false; }
}
return true;
```

Comment: I suspect C++ string index using `size_t` rather than `int`, which may be too narrow for _long_ strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the following?

Yes. Your code doesn't check the length of the strings, so if the first string is longer than the second string you can end up reading past the end of the second string. If the first string is a proper prefix of the second string your code returns the wrong result.

> Is one faster than the other?

Using the standard library functions will likely be the same or faster than your own function, because standard library functions can be optimized better. For example, the `==` operator might use `std::memcmp` to compare multiple characters at a time.

> Is there a better way to compare the strings than what is contained
>   here?

No, not really. `string1 == string2` is probably as good as it gets in terms of both simplicity and speed.

Comment: Good answer. Visual Studio actually does use `memcmp` as the implementation for `operator==`

Comment: Oops. Yes.  memcmp